# How to access `/.ssh` directory in windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, openssh

I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/762863/how-to-generate-ssh-keys-in-windows-10-and-windows-11/) using OpenSSH in Windows 10 and created an ssh key stored in this directory: `C:\Users\MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa` ,as the message I get says.

How do I actually find this directory from the windows `cmd` (or file explorer) so I can get my ssh key pair?

When I try to cd there I get an error that the directory does not exist.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of command prompt so we can see what exactly you're doing?

Comment: i did EXACTLY what it says in the link I provided I get the same message etc. I just cannot  find this path C:\Users\MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa. The screenshot in the link are identical to what I have.

Comment: It only shows how to create it, it's not showing us how YOU'RE trying to access it. I do those same commands all the time to generate keys and that path always exists for me just fine.

Comment: oh I do exactly what it says, i create the keys as in the link, it gives me this path, I try to to `cd C:\Users\MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa` and it gives me a ` PathNotFound` error

Comment: Finding the path `C:\Users\MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa` like you said is wayyyy different then actually trying to `cd` into the path. 

Do `cd C:\Users\MyUser/.ssh/` instead. If this works, I'll post it as an answer and we'll go from there.

Comment: yeah, it seems that everything after `MyUser` does not exist I can go in `MyUser` dir but there is no `.ssh` folder in there

Answer (score 1):

The default location for saving an SSH key is `C:\Users\username\.ssh`.

So if you open Windows Command Prompt, you should be able to see if there is a `.ssh/` subdirectory by using the change directory command like so:

`cd .ssh/` (you need the forward slash)

If it's there, you should get a new line:

`C:\Users\username\.ssh>`

and an error message if it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, ssh-keygen generated the keys inside the current directory, not into the path it claimed to generate them in. I was also following these instructions and was quite confused as well.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot proving that *ssh-keygen* generates the keys in a different directory from what it claims?

Comment: When it prompts "Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\user_name/.ssh/id_rsa):" the part in brackets is the suggested file name and location. If you write nothing and click enter, it is saved there, if you write a file name, then the keys are generated with that name to the current directory.